# Clarification on significance level and rejection region

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm going over the theory of hypothesis testing and I've hit a bump in trying to synthesize what exactly is happening with regards to significance levels and rejecting/ not rejecting a test. Let me quote the thoughts going on in my head and if I do have the right idea.

"Say we have chosen our significance level and we have arrived at the point where we have computed our test statistic, call it $t$. Say our test statistic falls into the rejection region we have chosen. Visually I am thinking something like this (this is just an example of a distribution that springs to mind, I don't have an exact distribution I am thinking about, just something to give me clarity):

[image]

What I have learned is that the significance level is the probability of a Type I error. So given that our test statistic $t$ falls into the rejection region, this means we would "reject" our null hypothesis."

It is this next part of the puzzle that I'm having trouble interpreting:  We calculated a specific test statistic, $t$ and it happens to fall in the rejection region. Does this mean that we have the probability of the test statistic $t$?

**OR**

is the reasoning: we calculated a test statistic $t$, it falls in the rejection region, but there is a 5% (chosen significance level) chance that I committed an error in rejecting the null hypothesis, but I am cool with that being the case.

But then how does the idea of "the probability of getting a specific value or higher" fit into the picture?

Comment: The picture suggests you are thinking about a specific test; taking that particular example might make things clearer. Based on data, we calculate the observed value of the test statistic and if this value falls in the rejection region we reject the null hypothesis at the given level of significance.

Comment: I'll edit and clarify with regards to the picture. So is there any probability attached to the calculated test statistic? Or is the only probability revolving around our significance level?

Comment: There is a probability distribution of the test statistic, of course.

Comment: Yes you're right, I mean we devised a distribution for the test statistic, silly me. So using that idea. We calculated a test statistic and say it fell at one of the extremes of our distribution. This means that the probability of getting that test statistic is very low. So because the probability of getting that statistic is low it would imply that the null hypothesis assumptions are incorrect and that's why we would "reject the null hypothesis"?

Answer (score 2):

The probability is the probability that we would observe these data conditional on the null hypothesis being true.

I suspect that your confusion may lie in the statement “What I have learned is that the significance level is the probability of a Type I error.” If by that you mean the unconditional probability of a Type I error (which is what one usually means by referring to a “probability” without qualifying it), then that’s wrong. The unconditional probability of a Type I error has no place in the frequentist framework of hypothesis testing. To assign an unconditional probability to the occurrence of a Type I error, we’d have to assign a prior probability to it (on which we could then do a Bayesian update using the observed data to get its posterior probability) – and frequentist hypothesis testing is in a sense all about avoiding to do that.

Comment: This brings more clarification for me actually. I have to remind myself that this is all operating under the premise of assuming that the null hypothesis is true....then we proceed. Thanks for the help

Comment: Type 1 error is by definition conditioned on null hypothesis being true.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: An error isn't conditioned on anything. A Type I error only occurs if the null hypothesis is true, but that doesn't prevent us from asking unconditionally: "What is the probability that we just made a Type I error in rejecting the null hypothesis?". Many people (including scientists who should know better) labour under the misunderstanding that this is what the significance level means.